# I have a problem with getting the id of some buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, append

With this app I will later try to control the lamps in my apartment. The problems are that I don't know how to get the id of the button. The Buttons are in a loop and I need the id to know which button is pressed.The Error I get is: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'buttonOn'

This is for a python app in TKinter to control some lamps in my apartment.

```
class Root(Tk):
 def __init__(self):
    super(Root, self).__init__()
    self.title('Lampensteuerung')
    self.geometry('1000x600')

    for l in lights:
        self.NameLamp = Label(self, text=lights[l].name)
        self.status= Label(self, text='Status:')
        self.statusLamp = Label(self, text=lights[l].on)
        self.brightness = Scale(self, from_=0, to=127, orient= HORIZONTAL)
        self.brightnessButton = Button(self, text='brightness control', width= 12, command = lambda: self.Brightness(c))
        self.buttonOn.append(Button(self, text='On', width=12, command = lambda c=l: self.LightOn(c)))
        self.buttonOff.append(Button(self, text='Off', width=12, command = lambda c=l: self.LightOff(c)))   

        self.NameLamp.grid(column=2, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.status.grid(column=3, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.statusLamp.grid(column=4, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.brightness.grid(column=5, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.brightnessButton.grid(column=6, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.buttonOn.grid(column=7, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)
        self.buttonOff.grid(column=8, row=l, ipady=20, ipadx=20)


def LightOn(self,c):
    if(c==1):
        lights[1].on = True
        self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[1].on)
    if(c==2):
        lights[2].on = True
        self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[2].on)
    if(c==3):
         lights[3].on = True
         self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[3].on)
    if(c==4):
        lights[4].on = True
        self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[4].on)
    if(c==5):
        lights[5].on = True
        self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[5].on)
    if(c==6):
        lights[6].on = True
        self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[6].on)
def LightOff(self,c):
    if(c==1):
        print("Licht 1 aus")

def Brightness(self,c):
    if(c==1):
        print("Helligkeit geändert")             
root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hard to tell w/o seeing where `lights` is defined, but on another topic, why not define the function `LightOn` as simply `lights[c].on = True; self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[c].on)` without all the `if` statements?

Comment: Also, `for l in lights` seems like it is expecting `l` to be an integer/index, yet `lights` is later treated as a subsettable object.  I'd start small, with one light and one button working, then scale it up.

Comment: Lights is a list. To be more specific in this list are 6 items. The Problem is that because of that error: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'buttonOn' the programm won't start. Also, I changed lights[l].on = True; self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[l].on) to lights[c].on = True; self.statusLamp.config(text=lights[c].on) as suggested above

Comment: If `lights` is a list, then shouldn't be using `lights[l]` You are either iterating through the list of items itself (so `l` is one light from the list), or using `enumerate(lights)` to get the index number. As it is, `lights[l].name` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Ok but still got the error

Comment: For better clarification. Here is the library how I control the lamps:   https://github.com/studioimaginaire/phue

Comment: It is too hard (and discouraged — we'll get a message shortly) to debug by these comments, but the `buttonOn` command is the first one where you are trying to append instead of define. I'd say get it working fully for just one light w/o any loops or list of lights and then try to expand.